# laravel 4 redirect to controller based off of conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Probably pretty simple, but I'm completely lost

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    if(Auth::check())
        // send traffic to \Controllers\Home@index
    else
        // send traffic to \Controllers\Loggedout\Home@index
});
```

I've tried:

- `Route::controller`
- `URL::action`
- `URL::route`
- `Redirect::route`

I have also named a two routes:

- `Route::get('/', array('as'=>'loggedin', 'uses'=>'Controllers\Home@index'));`
- `Route::get('/', array('as'=>'loggedout', 'uses'=>'Controllers\Loggedout\Home@index'));`

But it seems nothing is working.

I'm omitting the actual code to create the controller because it's quite standard and I know it works from `Route::get('/', 'Controllers\Home@index')` and it returns things properly.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote a nice lengthy answer to this only to realise that I misunderstood your question.

To my knowledge, there's no simple way to achieve what you're doing in a single route declaration, instead, you'll want to use two.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::get('/', array('as' => '\Controllers\Home@index'));
}

Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function() {
    Route::get('/', array('as' => '\Controllers\Loggedout\Home@index'));
}
```

Here we're using filters to group the individual calls so that they don't conflict. You shouldn't really be performing any extra logic within a route, but if you absolutely have to, then use a filter.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. First, in your routes:

```
// app/routes.php
Route::get('/', 'Controllers\Home@index');
```

Your controller:

```
// Controllers\Home class
class Home extends BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {

    }

}
```

And finally, your filters:

```
// app/filters.php
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if ( ! Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::action('Controllers\Loggedout\Home@index');
    }
});
```

Comment: When I use `return Redirect::action('Controllers\Loggedout\Home@index');`, I receive an error: `Unknown action [Controllers\Home@index]`.  Also, instead of putting the $this->beforeFilter in the controller, you could also do `Route::get('/', array('before'=>'auth', 'uses'=>'Controllers\Home@index'));`  However, both ways give me the error.

Comment: Check that you have your namespaces defined properly, included in `composer.json`, and did `composer dump-autoload` too. Yes, that could work too but assuming this is a "logged in" controller, you don't have to define the 'before' on every route this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the Redirect

```
 Route::get('/', function()
    {
        if(Auth::check())
            return Redirect::route('loggedin');
        else
            return Redirect::route('loggedout');
    });
```

Actually, this might just end up in a redirect loop as you are always returning back to /

Are you trying to show a different page depending on someones authentication status?

Comment: Yea, I kept receiving a redirect loop.  User is logged out->routes to loggedout->for some reason comes back to this get.  And yes, I'd like to show a loggedout screen if it's '/' but also the homepage if they're loggedin.

Answer (score 0):

My solution using just routes

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    if (Auth::check())
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    else
        return View::make('index');

});
```